# What is the difference between a public constructor which calls a class method and a class method that calls another class method?

Tags: php, class, constructor, class-method

I'm a little new to OO programming and am having trouble grasping why one mechanism works and another does not.

I've create a simple class that is to return a MySQL database handle. My attempt at returning the handle directly from a constructor fails. But succeeds from either a class method or from a class(?) method after an instance has been created. Here's the class definition and the sample script

```
<?php

class HMMDatabaseHandle {

        private static $configfile = "config.json";

// uncomment for test 1
//      public function __construct () {
//              return self::get_handle_admin();
//      }

        public static function create() {
                return self::get_handle_admin();
        }

        private static function get_handle_admin() {
                $config = json_decode(file_get_contents(self::$configfile));
                $dbhost = $config->database->dbhost;
                $dbname = $config->database->dbname;
                $dbuser = $config->database->dbuser;
                $dbpass = $config->database->dbpass;

                try {
                        return new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
                }
                        catch(PDOException $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                }
        }
}

?>
```

And here is the test script I'm using:

```
<?php
require_once 'HMMDatabaseHandle.php';

// Test 1 - fails (uncomment constructor func) at call to prepare() with:
// PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method HMMDatabaseHandle::prepare()
//$dbh = new HMMDatabaseHandle();

// Test 2 - works when class creates default constructor
// i.e. no explicit __construct() func
// Fetching data from executed query is fine
//$db = new HMMDatabaseHandle();
//$dbh = $db->create();

// Works using static class methods rather than instance
$dbh = HMMDatabaseHandle::create();

$sth = $dbh->prepare('select data_title,track_id from master');
$sth->execute();
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   ...
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why can't I return the handle directly from a constructor when it seems so similar to calling the class method directly? Why does it matter whether the constructor calls the class method or my script calls it?
2. If I create an instance with PHP's default constructor, am I really calling a class method with $db->create()?

I seem to be missing some fundamental concept here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Class constructors return the newly created object - nothing else. Well, that's not entirely true. The `new` keyword actually returns it but the constructor function is usually used in conjunction with it which makes it appear that the constructor is returning it. You can think of the __construct function as a place to execute some code as the class is being instantiated. It actually returns nothing/void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return the handle from the constructor in that context because that would violate the defined behavior of [`new`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new). `new SomeClass();` will only ever return an instance of the class, regardless of what other methods are called in the constructor.

[`__construct()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.construct) is a void method. It is not *intended* to return anything<sup>1</sup>. That doesn't mean that the other code in it doesn't get executed, just that your `return` is disregarded in the context of creating a new object. This makes sense as the primary purpose for the constructor is to provide a means to pass dependencies to the object. Sometimes it is used to do additional initialization/setup of the object, but many people believe it should not do any work other than assigning the given arguments to the object's properties. Either way, there should be no need for it to return anything.

---

<sup>1</sup> You *can* actually call the `__construct()` method explicitly *after* you create the object, and then it will behave like a normal method and your `return` will work.

```
$db = new HMMDatabaseHandle();
$dbh = $db->__construct();
var_dump($dbh);  // PDO Object
```

This isn't a normal thing to do though, and I can't think of a scenario where it would be useful or desirable. I just wanted to point out that it is possible.

Comment: Ah! I get it now! Thanks!  So I could, for example, call get_handle_admin() fromthe constructor to set an instance variable and then fetch that later with an instance method: $this->handle = self::get_handle_admin()

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, you could do that. I would suggest reading up on dependency injection, though. Classes that create their own dependencies internally can be difficult to test.

Comment: Fair enough. The dependecy you are referencing is the database call? Yeah, I've been struggling with how to abstract connectivity to the database in this OOP world. There seem to be a LOT of opinions on the matter. :-)

Comment: I'm referring to the PDO object itself. If you can assign a PDO object to your class, either through the constructor or with a setter, then you will be able to mock it during testing. If it's created within the class, then any testing will depend on a real connection to a database.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't I return the handle directly from a constructor when it
>   seems so similar to calling the class method directly?

If you were able to do that, then you wouldn't have an instance of `HMMDatabaseHandle`; you'd have an instance of `PDO`. How would you access any other methods that `HMMDatabaseHandle` provides?

---

While I fully agree with @Don't Panic's answer, I need to also point out that you're mixing static and instance methods.

As a general rule of thumb, use the `static` keyword when you want to be able to call a method without instantiating the object first. If you want to actually create and use an *object*, then you can define you class like so and use `$this->` (or `$object->` if outside of the class) instead of `::` to access *instance* properties and methods.

```
<?php
class HMMDatabaseHandle
{

    private $configfile = "config.json";


    public function __construct()
    {
        // You're not initializing anything in here, so this constructor is optional.
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return $this->get_handle_admin();
    }

    private function get_handle_admin()
    {
        $config = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->configfile));
        $dbhost = $config->database->dbhost;
        $dbname = $config->database->dbname;
        $dbuser = $config->database->dbuser;
        $dbpass = $config->database->dbpass;

        try {
            return new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

To actually execute this, you need to now instantiate new class.

```
$dbManager = new HMMDatabaseHandle();
$handle = $dbManager->create();
```

Finally, there is a trick you can employ to make your constructor *chainable*. Simply wrap it in brackets.

```
$handle = (new HMMDatabaseHandle())->create();
```

Comment: Thanks! So nothing *prevents* one from calling a static method as an instance method. It's just bad form?  That explains why test 2 works. Thanks for the tip on chainable constructors as well.

Comment: _So nothing prevents one from calling a static method as an instance method._ Correct - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3d8a642dcade680c5d00e78f8886a79e39fa75a. Read more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static